# Java equivalent of PHP/CURL's curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/path/to/file.pem');

Tags: java, php, ssl, curl

In PHP, I use CURL to send a .PEM formatted certificate to a remote host. For example:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/path/to/file.pem');
```

How can I do this in Java?